# Python: Behaviour of os.access is for uid or euid?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python script which runs as ROOT user.
I need to test if a user with UID 1000 has read access on particular file.

What I am trying is fork a child, then seteuid(1000) and then os.access function.

I have 2 queries:

1. From the documentation I can't figure out if this operates on real UID or the effective UID ?
2. Also, I am trying the following code in python interactive console invoked by ROOT:

   ```
   import os
   os.seteuid(1000)
   with open('/etc/myfile', 'w') as f:
     pass

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/myfile'
   ```

So effective UID is changed to 1000 which can't create file in /etc/ which is AS EXPECTED.

But if I further check for read permission on a file where 1000 doesn't have permission I still get True with is NOT EXPECTED:

```
os.access('/tmp/level1/level2/junk', os.R_OK)
True
```

Why is that ? I even tried with os.setuid(1000) but same result

If I login as that user(1000) and do ls on that path, I get permission denied AS EXPECTED

Comment: Ok, here is a finding which looks like I have answered my own question.

But I would still like some expert to validate this.
In my case, as the script/python interactive shell, though I was changing the UID/GID but the supplementary group list was still having 0 in the groups list. Which is what was giving me True where it was not expected

After I change the code to:

        `os.setgroups([1000]) in addition to setgid and setuid`

I get False on os.access as EXPECTED

Is this correct that the supplementary groups will contribute in access checks too after setuid/setgid call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, as the script/python interactive shell, though I was changing the UID/GID but the supplementary group list was still having 0 in the groups list.
Which is what was giving me True where it was not expected

After I change the code to `os.setgroups([1000])` in addition to setgid and setuid I get False on os.access as EXPECTED

So basically it was the supplementary groups which was allowing access.